# UITableview not display data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, hpple

Hey guys I am using Hpple to get some data from the web and display it in a table view. I am using the code from ray wenderlich. The source code is available at the bottom of this page http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios. Then this is the website I am using to get the data http://ueat.site88.net/output.xml. And here is my xPathQuery

```
//day[@name='monday']/meal[@name='LUNCH']/counter[@name='Entrée']/dish/name.
```

It gets the info if I NSLog what should go in the table view

```
Tutorial *thisTutorial = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@", thisTutorial.title);
cell.textLabel.text = thisTutorial.title;
```

but then it doesn't appear in the table view, I know the nodes are not nil.

Heres the code for where it display the data

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

#import "TFHpple.h"
#import "Tutorial.h"
#import "Contributor.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
    NSMutableArray *_contributors;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

@synthesize detailViewController = _detailViewController;

- (void)loadTutorials {
    // 1
    NSURL *tutorialsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ueat.site88.net/output.xml"];
    NSData *tutorialsHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:tutorialsUrl];


    // 2
    TFHpple *tutorialsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:tutorialsHtmlData];

    // 3
    NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//day[@name='monday']/meal[@name='LUNCH']/counter[@name='Entrée']/dish/name";
    NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];

    // 4
    NSMutableArray *newTutorials = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (TFHppleElement *element in tutorialsNodes) {
        // 5
        Tutorial *tutorial = [[Tutorial alloc] init];
        [newTutorials addObject:tutorial];

        // 6
        tutorial.title = [[element firstChild] content];
        NSLog(@"%@", tutorial.title);

        // 7
        tutorial.url = [element objectForKey:@"href"];
    }

    // 8
    _objects = newTutorials;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
/*
- (void)loadContributors {
    // 1
    NSURL *contributorsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.raywenderlich.com/about"];
    NSData *contributorsHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:contributorsUrl];

    // 2
    TFHpple *contributorsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:contributorsHtmlData];

    // 3
    NSString *contributorsXpathQueryString = @"//ul[@class='team-members']/li";
    NSArray *contributorsNodes = [contributorsParser searchWithXPathQuery:contributorsXpathQueryString];

    // 4
    NSMutableArray *newContributors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (TFHppleElement *element in contributorsNodes) {
        // 5
        Contributor *contributor = [[Contributor alloc] init];
        [newContributors addObject:contributor];

        // 6
        for (TFHppleElement *child in element.children) {
            if ([child.tagName isEqualToString:@"img"]) {
                // 7
                @try {
                    contributor.imageUrl = [@"http://www.raywenderlich.com" stringByAppendingString:[child objectForKey:@"src"]];
                }
                @catch (NSException *e) {}
            } else if ([child.tagName isEqualToString:@"h3"]) {
                // 8
                contributor.name = [[child firstChild] content];
            }
        }
    }

    // 9
    _contributors = newContributors;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
 */

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self loadTutorials];
//    [self loadContributors];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}


#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return @"Tutorials";
            break;
        case 1:
            return @"Contributors";
            break;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return _objects.count;
            break;
        case 1:
            return _contributors.count;
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        Tutorial *thisTutorial = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%@", thisTutorial.title);
        cell.textLabel.text = thisTutorial.title;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = thisTutorial.url;
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        Contributor *thisContributor = [_contributors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = thisContributor.name;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.detailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    NSDate *object = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Alex, I'll take "Table View Data Sources & Delegates" for 100 please.

Comment: This question doesn't come close to providing enough detail to know what issue you are having.

Comment: @rmaddy basically Hpple gets the data, but the tableview will not display it

Comment: And how that does that help us help you? You show absolutely no information about how you try to show the data in a table.

Comment: @rmaddy i have posted the code of my view controller, its exactly the same as the sample code from the ray wenderlich site except my xPath and my website

Comment: Do you get the NSLog statements from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` printed on the console?

Comment: Now that you have posted your code, what happens? What debugging have you done? Does the `numberOfSections:` method get called? What about `numberOfRowsInSection`? Does it return the correct numbers?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes they print on the console and when I drag the table up and down the log keeps printing things out.

Comment: Can you see the section headings?  And do the section headings contain the title strings?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, i can see then and yes then return the strings

Comment: I downloaded the sample project and ran it unmodified, and it worked fine.  There are some blank rows, probably due to bad data - I haven't looked into it.  So, what did you change?

Comment: @Paulw11 the only thing I changes was I changed the site to the one i posted in the question, and the xPathQuery to the one I posted, and then I get all blank rows do you get the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simply that your first element contains new line characters.  If you strip these out -

```
tutorial.title = [[[element firstChild] content]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

then the table rows display correctly.

Comment: so those new line characters are in the xml, on the website correct?

Comment: yes, they are.  Whitespace doesn't matter to XML so if you display the XML in a browser you won't see them, but when I stepped through the code with the debugger you could see them in the string